# Syslog-NG with mysql phpmyamdin not storing data real time?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have installed syslog-ng on an ubuntu 18.04.4lts. but it looks like mysql is missing some logs. when I run syslog-ng -d I can see logs are coming in real time. But in phpmyadmin they are at least 25-30min behind. Furthermore, it is happening everyday. I have also made the changes so that there is no limit of mysql to store data. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refrain from writing in All Caps as it makes your text more difficult to read and some people perceive that as if you're shouting!

Answer (score 1):

Please adjust spelling, reading this in all caps sounds like you're screaming.

Comment: my mistake..but looks stackoverflow changed the texts to normal already.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, as long as you refresh the page, you're seeing data as MySQL/MariaDB stores it; there's no delay or caching on the MySQL <--> phpMyAdmin connection. Any delay you're seeing as described here would have to be explained by syslog-ng; is there some sort of cache involved where it delays writing events to the database? That would make the most sense about why `syslog-ng -d` shows you the relevant logs but it takes some time to propagate to MySQL.

Really, I don't know much about using syslog-ng in this way, but based on your explanation of events, the answer has to lie there somewhere.